# Android show gallery with specific sdcard folder

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have an android app that takes images and videos from an external camera connected to the device and saves it in a folder on the sdcard. There is a button which launches the gallery, I want that the gallery be opened just like the camera gallery, showing both the photos and videos in that folder. How can this be done?

Presently I am implementing MediaScannerConnectionClient in my Activity, but this opens up an app chooser based on the last clicked image/recorded video and then shows only the last image.

On the button click listener, I am calling startScan()

```
private void startScan(){
    Log.d("Connected","success"+conn);
    if(conn!=null)
    {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    conn = new MediaScannerConnection(this,this);
    conn.connect();
}
@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    Log.d("onMediaScannerConnected","success"+conn);


    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    String[] allFiles = folder.list();
    conn.scanFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+appFolderName, FILE_TYPE);           
}


@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    try {
        Log.d("onScanCompleted",uri + "success"+conn);
        if (uri != null) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } finally 
    {
        conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: No, not yet. Please upvote the question if you haven't already.